# How do detect what overrides css properties of ReactJS components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

:)

I have been developing a webpage for some time now, and I decided to use a react-calendar component from [here](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar). In the beginning, when page was lightweight it worked out of the box and, following the example on the webpage, my page rendered this:

[image]

Later on in the development, as i added more complexity to the page, calendar became completely disfigured and only displays plainly, like this:

[image]

I thought something was overriding my calendar's css properties and tried putting it outside the app div like this:

```
<div>
    <Calendar/>
    <App/>
</div>
```

But calendar's appearance remains unchanged. After inspecting elements in browser I noticed some suspicious crossed out values:

[image]

Is there a way of preventing parent override of calendar's css properties? Or am i missing something crucial in code which would make the calendar look neat again? It always looks neat if I install and use it in a clean project (but i'd love to have a working one everywhere :D).

Thanks in advance for your advices! :)

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CSS property you can almost always override it. There is no way to tell (for example using javascript) if a css value has been overridden, since it's the browser who does this. Maybe there is something in your code that changed the behaviour by adding a parent class that overrides all its children, or a major CSS style sheet like bootstrap that overrides some others. If this is your case, it's hard to tell without looking at the code.

**Good news**

You can completely prevent CSS inheritance, by wrapping your component in an `iframe`.

**Or**

You can have properties that can almost never be overridden, depending on CSS specificity.

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold")
>   always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be
>   thought of as having the highest specificity.

Have a read at the complete article to understand how it works. This statement though, says that you can always override properties if they are set inline. Now, the problem of using a third-party component is that you cannot set the styles for everything used by the component, and of course the point on using a third-party component is that you don't need to bother about these configurations.

Apart from using inline styles, you can also set the `!important` flag to your CSS styles, but we come to the problem of the third-party component again.

I suggest these approaches:

**1) Create CSS rule to reset values to initial**

Basically create a rule called `NoInheritanceCalendar` for example, that will reset any rules before the calendar's rules.

Set your code to:

```
<div className="NoInheritanceCalendar">
    <Calendar/>
</div>
```

and in your CSS:

```
div.NoInheritanceCalendar {
    all: initial;
}
```

**2) Wrap it in an iframe**

Although not the best approach, this is the only way you could prevent inheritance at all.

**3) Copy component's style sheet, add prefix class to all properties so that they are more specific.**

If your third-party component's CSS is:

```
.rule1 {
    font ...
    width ...
}

.rule2 {
    font ...
    width ...
}

.rule3 {
    font ...
    width ...
}
```

You can create a prefix class to make those more specific:

```
.MyClass.rule1 {
    font ...
    width ...
}

.MyClass.rule2 {
    font ...
    width ...
}

.MyClass.rule3 {
    font ...
    width ...
}
```

and add your component in react as:

```
<div className="MyClass">
    <Calendar/>
</div>
```

These tools help you with this if it is a big style sheet:

- [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)
- [prefixfree](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree)
- [less-plugin-autoprefix](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix)

Comment: Thank you for extensive reply! :) I read the articles and tried your approach with all:initial and with !important, sadly it just changes the font on the calendar. I suspect there might be another style sheet perhaps, in the root of the page. Personally, i dislike the iframe solution but will give that one a shot if all else fails. I was thinking too, about the approach 2 you suggested, by basically copying entire style sheet of the calendar but that was also my last resort since it feels counterintuitive (not to mention unnecessary duplication).

Comment: @Traumy yes, iframes not my thing either, but are the only real way to prevent this. There has to be a stylesheet somewhere that is doing something like `.new-class-selector * { ... }` which is modifying your calendar, amongst other things. Problem is what you see in the css inspector doesn't seem to help. Try another browser, to see if the code inspector tells you which css file is overriding your classes.